# Database structure for daily checkoff / task lists

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, database-schema

My Fire dept has asked me to build an app to move our daily and weekly truck checkoff records to a database & integrate into the existing members site. I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure this.

There are 10 trucks and each has it's own weekly checkoff procedure.

Here's one for reference --->

[image]

- All fields are boolean (other than notes field).
- The fields are subject to change occasionally (new equipment, etc).

There's also a daily checkoff on our two "First Out" engines. This is basically just a shorter version of the weekly checkoffs above.

Daily checkoff form --->

[image]

How would you structure this database?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your problem is quite similar to a general "form/questionnaire".

As such I suggest something like [this other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11970) as a starting point (of course you better read the other answers to the same question).

Your case is "simpler" because apparently you have only two types of answers: booleans and text notes.

Basically every different truck will be a questionnaire, and be careful to properly model (and mantain) the concept of version (so that if you add some new equipment or check to a truck, you just add the question/step to the master questionnaire and from then on the correct set of questions/answers will become available to the user.